# PySpark how to read csv files with different columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, amazon-emr

I'm loading CSV files from different providers

s3://data-bucket/sources/provider-1.csv

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
```

s3://data-bucket/sources/provider-2.csv

```
root
 |-- sid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
```

s3://data-bucket/sources/provider-3.csv

```
root
 |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- currency: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
```

Different provider has different columns & different order.

```
schema_list = []
for field in ['sid', 'pid', 'name', 'price', 'currency', 'color', 'gender']:
    schema_list.append(StructField(field, StringType(), True))
schema = StructType(schema_list)

df = spark.read.csv(
    header=True,
    schema=schema,
    sep="\t",
    quote="\"",
    escape="\"",
    path='s3://data-bucket/sources/*.csv',
    ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True,
    ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=True,
)
df.write.parquet('s3://data-bucket/output/', mode="overwrite")
```

Basically what I want to do here, is to normalize the columns from all providers, and output to parquet format. But the output data are messed up.

Any way to load multiple files with different columns?

Comment: these are csv, the order of the columns is important, the existence of the colum is important ... you cannot change the schema just like this. You need to have a input dataframe for each source, and then apply mapping rules to each on them to create one unique dataframe.

Comment: While not ideal, one alternative would be to load those CSVs without a schema (infer) and convert them to RDDs. Then union the RDDs and create a Dataframe with your schema. You can read a write up about a similar issue with JSON here https://medium.com/data-arena/merging-different-schemas-in-apache-spark-2a9caca2c5ce

Comment: After reading each file as suggested by @Steven, you can use `unionByName` to create a combined dataframe, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html

Comment: Thanks all. I tried the `unionByName`, it works, but very inefficient, it took 50min to normalize _(in my existing process in pure python, only took 3min)_. I also follow the link by @Gaarv, the job force cancelled halfway. Anyway, thanks for all the suggestions